# Create case with template via REST API

Tags: rest-api, case, rest, template

I would like to create a case that asks for data to be filled in via something like an HTML form.

My research so far indicates that a Template is the weapon of choice for the "form".

I want to create both the case and the Template using the Rest API, so the whole thing is created automatically by our backend, which will poll the case to determine when it's been Closed and collect the data entered into the template.

I have got the case creation working OK via the Rest API, and the polling, but can't figure out how to add a template to it that needs to be filled in.

Any guidance appreciated.

---

Edit:

Is it possible to have a case render a form obtained from a company http endpoint? Ans save any input entered within the case? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to create a custom case page layout in the admin console (there is no API for creating them) here

> http://your-org.lightning.force.com/lightning/setup/ObjectManager/Case/PageLayouts/view

Case page layouts have customized fields - create one suitable for capturing the data needed for each situation you want to handle. When creating the case via the API, specify your custom case type as the type for the case.

The great thing about this approach is it requires no special integration or functionality - it all comes out of the box.

It has the side benefit of being able to *remove* the many fields that aren't relevant to data collection that are in the default case types.